# Angular 2 - Authentication does not work with multipart/formdata

Tags: angular, authentication, spring-boot, authorization

I am trying to upload file using this code:

```
    headers: Headers;

    token = '';

    @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('profilePic') profilePic:ElementRef;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private api: ApiService) {}

    upload(fileToUpload:File) {

    this.token = window.localStorage.getItem('jwt_key');

    console.log('Bearer ' + this.token);

    this.headers = new Headers({Authorization :'Bearer ' + this.token });
    this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

    let input = new FormData();
    input.append('file', fileToUpload);

    return this.api
        .postFile('/profile/upload', input, this.headers).subscribe(
            res => console.log(res.detailedResult),
            err => console.log(err)
```

But keeping getting error from chrome browser that: `error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource`. So how do I upload a file to a url that needs authentication?

Comment: Is the error message coming from Chrome, or is it the response to the `http` request?

Comment: It a response from http, it hits my breakpoint when I removed authentication from my backend.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like a problem with your backend.

Comment: I have seen a number of solutions for fileuploading with springboot, but I haven't seen a good one, is there a solution for that? pls.

Comment: I would recommend posting a question aimed towards your backend code and tagged appropriately. From what I can see, this is not an issue with Angular or the front end.

Comment: I see. I confirm that.

Answer (score -1):

This worked:

```
headers: Headers;

token = '';


@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('profilePic') profilePic:ElementRef;

constructor(private element: ElementRef, private api: ApiService) {}

upload(fileToUpload:File) {

this.token = window.localStorage.getItem('jwt_key');

this.headers = new Headers();

this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);

this.api.removeHeader('Content_Type');

this.api.setHeaders(this.headers);

let input = new FormData();

return this.api.post ('/profile/upload', input).subscribe(
        res => console.log(res.detailedResult),
        err => console.log(err)
    );
```

I appended `Authorization`, and removed the previous `Content-type`.